# How can I fix PostgreSQL setup problem from Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I created PostgreSQL in Django project. When I do migrate for database it's return this exception.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql'
isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'
```

I tried `postgresql_psycopg2` and `pip install psycopg2-binary` but doesn't  work.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'eatadil',
        'USER': 'postgre',
        'PASSWORD': 'realpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you working in a virtual environment?  If so, did you install psycopg2-binary into the virtual environment?

Comment: Yes i am working virtual env. I downloaede psycop2-binary but not find postgresql

Comment: This problem not fixed. Why i can't use PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved.

You can only update django last version.